# Setting value to struct pointers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    char** thingSize;
} Thing;

typedef struct {
    Thing* thing;
} Game;

void load_array(Thing* thing) {
    int i, j;
    char **emptyThing = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    emptyThing = malloc(sizeof(char*)*9);
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
        emptyThing[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*9);
    }
    thing -> thingSize = emptyThing;
    free(emptyThing);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Game* game;
    load_array(game -> thing);
    printf("HI");
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault, I have found that the problem line is.
`thing -> thingSize = emptyThing;`
I am trying to set thingSize to be a 2d array equal to emptyThing.

Comment: Where do you get the magic number `9` from?

Comment: `game` is not initialized...

Comment: Your whole code looks pretty pointless. I think you should study pointers and try to write really simple programs involving pointers before trying to write code that involve multiple pointers, pointer to pointers, arrays of pointers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fredrik said, the game pointer is not initialized to anything. It hold a garbage value, when dereferencing it, you will get a segfault.